# What is an Ihh-/- mouse?

Tags: lab-techniques, animal-models

This one is too basic question:

I just came across $Ihh^{-/-}\ $ mouse. Is that means this mouse devoid of that gene Ihh. What is this sign called and are there other such representations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are allele notations or nomenclatures and they refer to a gene, and what changes a particular gene has undergone, if any. In this case, the -/- refers to the fact that the *Ihh* gene is homozygous for a null mutation as correctly stated by @Alan Boyd. This [page](http://www.informatics.jax.org/mgihome/nomen/allmut_quickhelp.shtml) has further examples of allele nomenclatures. This [page](http://www.informatics.jax.org/mgihome/nomen/gene.shtml#navsma), which can be reached from the previous link provides comprehensive guidelines for nomenclature of genes, genetic markers, alleles, and mutations in mouse and rat. Please note that (if you look at the examples [here](http://flystocks.bio.indiana.edu/Fly_Work/nomenclature.htm)) a nomenclature can be different in different species for example in the fly field, you tend not to use the -/- sign to denote a null mutation and instead it can be a name or a number for example *Rab5(1)*. The only reason this is called allele 1 is that it shows the most severe phenotype, which is embryonic lethality. You can read [this paper here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12743108) for some of the *Rab5* alleles produced in *Drosophila*.

Answer (score 4):

The *IHH* gene encodes the [Indian hedgehog homolog protein](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IHH_(protein)), a member of the family of hedgehog proteins that  regulates bone formation. The *ihh<sup>-/-</sup>* notation represents an animal which is homozygous for a null mutation in the gene (i.e. the animal has no functional *IHH* gene).

Comment: Thanks. Can you add the other signs which are used? like for heterzygous it will be +/- or -/+. (Sorry, I know it's too basic.)

Comment: @DevashishDas it's generally `+/-` for hets